# Adding missing colon to time column in a table

Tags: text-processing, date

I have table like this one:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
06/28/2004,0931,37.49,37.50,37.45,37.46,1049200
06/28/2004,0932,37.48,37.50,37.45,37.48,450700
06/28/2004,0933,37.48,37.50,37.46,37.49,493700
06/28/2004,0934,37.49,37.50,37.47,37.47,756100
06/28/2004,0935,37.48,37.49,37.46,37.48,309000
```

Unfortunately, the time column just numbers and missing `:` between the pairs of numbers. How can I correct that so the time in the table is correctly visualized like this:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
06/28/2004,09:31,37.49,37.50,37.45,37.46,1049200
06/28/2004,09:32,37.48,37.50,37.45,37.48,450700
06/28/2004,09:33,37.48,37.50,37.46,37.49,493700
06/28/2004,09:34,37.49,37.50,37.47,37.47,756100
06/28/2004,09:35,37.48,37.49,37.46,37.48,309000
```

Comment: For all these sorts of questions, it would be better to modify the process that produces the data rather than adding an extra post-processing step.  I understand that this is not always possible, but it would be better.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree but believe me it is not possible at all!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vFS="" -vOFS="" 'NR>1 {$13=$13":"}1' file

"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
06/28/2004,09:31,37.49,37.50,37.45,37.46,1049200
06/28/2004,09:32,37.48,37.50,37.45,37.48,450700
06/28/2004,09:33,37.48,37.50,37.46,37.49,493700
06/28/2004,09:34,37.49,37.50,37.47,37.47,756100
06/28/2004,09:35,37.48,37.49,37.46,37.48,309000
```

`-vFS="" -vOFS=""` sets the input and output field separators to non.

`NR>1` to avoid changes on the first row, meaning changes will be applied starting row #2

`{$13=$13":"}` will insert colon after string 13

Comment: thank you, I found mistake in my table the time in header is adding an extra `:`, which is showing up in your solution. I fixed the table how can I remove the ":" from in front the time in the header. thanks!

Comment: @Shervan see my edits please!